# A closed form for $\int_R^{\infty} x^{2\nu+1}J_{\nu}(x)\exp\{-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}\}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Can the integral

$$I(R,\sigma)\equiv \int_R^{\infty} x^{2\nu+1}J_{\nu}(x)\exp\{-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}\}dx$$

be written in a closed form in terms of elementary functions? Here $\nu$ is a positive integer, $J_{\nu}(x)$ is a Bessel function of the first kind, $\sigma$ is positive, and $R$ is large and positive such that the asymptotic approximation $J_{\nu}(x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\nu-\frac{\pi}{4})$ is a valid approximation in the integration region.

Comment: Even with the asymptotic approximation for the Bessel, the integral is still not elementary. I expect a sum of (incomplete) gamma functions of complex argument

Comment: If you want an asymptotic approximation for large $R$, I think it can have an elementary form... Here are the asymptotics for incomplete gamma, which may be useful: https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11

Comment: You can definitely write the integral in terms of a series of incomplete gamma functions by using the series representation of the Bessel function. Since the series expansion is infinite, this can be used to numerically approximate the integral but not find a closed form solution.

Comment: T-Ray, no, I meant that your cosine approximation immediately leads to a sum of two incomplete gammas, after you represent the cosine in exponential form

Comment: For $R = 0$, this integral looks a lot like a Hankel Transform evaluated at $y = 1$.  In this document, https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/7/Volume%202.pdf , see Section 8.2 transform pair (21).  For the case of $\nu = 0$, you've got a gamma function and a hypergeometric function as part of the answer.  If you can't use easily use the definition of the Hankel Transform in that document, see the "Definition" and "Alternate Definition" section of the Wikipedia page to transform things:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform